# What resource do I query to get SOLR results?

Tags: magento, solr, catalog

I have SOLR working on my website and outside of more config tweaks it works.

So now I want to tie in an autocomplete top search that uses SOLR results.

I have

```
$results = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogsearch/fulltext_collection');
$results->addSearchFilter($query->getQueryText())
->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore())
->addMinimalPrice()
->addFinalPrice()
->addStoreFilter()
->addTaxPercents();
```

but I am getting different results then on my search results page. What am I doing wrong?